# How do I use basil.js with browserify?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, browserify

I want to use [the basil package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basil.js) with browserify to manage cookies.

I've run `npm install --save basil` and that worked OK.

Now I am trying this in my JS:

```
require('basil');
var basil = new window.Basil();
```

But this fails with `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

What should I do instead?

I've tried this too, just guessing:

```
var Basil = require('basil');
var basil = new window.Basil();
```

How am I supposed to know how to include it?

Comment: Try removing 'window.' as it isn't needed either way.

Comment: To clarify: window.x == x. this is because window is the global namespace in the browser. e.g window.location.reload() == location.reload()

Comment: sure, thanks, was just trying to copy the documentation, doesn't make any difference either way...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`var Basil = require('basil');
var basil = new Basil();`

Edit: As for your question in how you're meant to know how to include.. take a look at the `basil.js` source code, line 17.

```
function Basil() {
    if (!(this instanceof Basil)) return new Basil;
    this.handlers = [];
}

/**
 * Expose `Basil`.
 */
exports = module.exports = Basil;
```

The `Basil` function itself is being exposed as the export, so this is what you want to call new on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When I try that I get no import errors, but then I just get `basil.get is not a function` when I try `basil.get('something')`.